# How to force Inno Setup to overwrite files in use?

Tags: inno-setup

I use Inno Setup to distribute my application. But this application have three files that can be used by another applications of enterprise.

So, when I release a new version of my application, this files cannot be replaced until the machine restarts. But, my application is an windows service and I cannot force the restart and I also cannot restart the other applications.

Is there any way to force this files to be replaced by the Inno Setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You cannot replace files that are locked by other applications.

You have to close those applications, before you will be able to replace the files.

Or consider having a separate copy of the files for each application.

Or (if applicable), modify the applications not to lock the files.

---

*If you want more concrete answers, you will have to tell us, what are the files, why the applications share the files, etc.*

Comment: Thanks, Martin. I will consider the 4th question with the our dsn-team!